# Limit access to remote server via particular vpn

Tags: vpn, remote-access, remote

I need to ask a question.

1. there are multiple users of server, all connecting via vpn.
2. each using openvpn-cert based connection (linux)

I'd like to find a way to limit vpn connection to "trusted" devices only, added to the server and prevent to log in from the other devices.
The point is to have a better control of logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f you are using OpenVPN I think you can use the ccd-exclusive directive

> --ccd-exclusive
>   Require, as a condition of authentication, that a connecting client has a --client-config-dir file.

You will need to configure the client-config-dir directive and then create a file in that directory named after the client's X509 common name

For example if you have a client with an X509 common name of my_client and you configure

```
ccd-exclusive
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn.ccd
```

Then the file /etc/openvpn/ccd/my_client has to exist (it can be blank) for the client to be allowed to connect.

Comment: How about an access to the remote resources (eg. vcenter)?

Comment: There's no problem to restrict remote share. I want to prevent in case of any installation of vpn on the other than "company" device.
If someone will use any other than authorized device - the connection will not happen - that's the case :)
I suppose that will need an external service like eg. Barracuda, Fortigate etc.